# Why should I not put my PHP files in the public_html folder?

Tags: php, security

Some days ago someone criticize me about putting my application scripts inside `public_html` folder. Until then I thought that the the `755` file permission would be enough to keep my code from being read instead of executing.

I don't like the idea that nowadays a lest half of our application logic is public for the eyes in the form of `JavaScript` and they come from the public folder. But what is the real threat about the PHP scripts?

Comment: Was this person talking about stuff such as your config files etc.? You need to put your php files in the public folder to make them accessible to the...public

Comment: the stuff you mention is in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371997/how-to-add-a-rule-to-the-zend-url-mapping-and-compose-multiple-mvc-paths :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is typically that JavaScript code is *untrusted* code (or at least it should be, since it's running on the client), whereas PHP code is usually considered *trusted* code (since it runs on the server where it can't be directly interfered with by users).

As such, someone discovering a hole in PHP source often has access to much greater privileges if they can exploit it than someone who discovers a hole in JavaScript code, since they can get PHP to run something server-side.

Now, while security through obscurity should not be your *primary* means of securing your code - it's always best to not have security holes in the first place - it's also generally not a good idea to make it *easier* for an attacker to locate a hole that somehow got introduced. Keeping things out of the non-script serving root helps prevent accidents ("oops, I accidentally disabled PHP, everyone who requests a page gets the source code instead") from occurring.

Furthermore, server-side files may include things like configuration data that is not meant to be public - internal network addresses, database info, et cetera (though it's also a good idea to keep things like credentials separate from your PHP code as well).

Comment: I can see your point. If the server admin disables the PHP module in Apache or some other error occur in this interface, my files might be available for reading. Will my PHP files still be runnable if I put a 711 permission to them?

Comment: You have given me a few tips

Comment: User Brandon Enriquez answered a question like this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824482/placing-the-php-application-folder-above-public-html?rq=1

Comment: ...and he says that if you can figure it out the user name, you can hack into the PHP files even if they are out of the public_html folder, by using the real file path.

Comment: @EASI That answer assumes someone can run code on your server. `public_html` is what's available to the web at large, generally, not just people on your own server.

Comment: I uses to think that Linux was secure... :-/

Comment: @EASI security is not an inherent property of an OS, only how it's used.